# Play console app stuck on "Ready to send for review"

Tags: android, android-studio, publish, google-play-console

I'm a little bit confused regarding the update of my application on the play store.
Please check the below-given images and suggest to me what I can do now.
[image: Image 1 "App Status"]

[image: Image 2 "Publishing Overview"]

In image-1 it is showing app ready to send for review
In image 2 there is no option to send for review in the publishing overview.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: i am having the same issue with Play Console!! i had clicked the Send for Review in Publishing Overview page and all changes are in Review. But on the Dashboard and App page it says update status is Ready to send for review.

Comment: Please let me know if you will find any solution

Comment: My update is live now just fix the issues and and create a new release

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one more step . "Ready to send for review" means everything is ready to send for review . What you have to do is . Go to "Publishing overview" on the left and to right side of Changes in review , there will be a button to Send for review

You will notice that the status will change to  "In Review" .. Then it might take 2-3 week or more . It is actually at that point the waiting starts

Answer (score 0):

There is no more thing you need to do rather than waiting.

Just wait, it took me last time 2 weeks.